# Angularjs 1.x issue display data

Tags: angularjs

```
{
"Name":aaaaa,
"2019":343245,
"2018":208546,
2017":521756,
"2015":653567
}
```

How to display above json data in angularjs
`ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better change the JSON to something like this.

```
datasource = { "Name":aaaaa, "data":["2019":343245, "2018":208546, 2017":521756, "2015":653567] }
```

The you can show this in a table like bellow

```
<table *ngIf="dataSource">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <th *ngRepeat="(key,value) in datasource">
            {{key}}
    </th>
</tr>
<tr *ngRepeat="(key,value) in datasource">
    <td>{{value.Name}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="(key, val) in value.data">
        {{val}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I think this might help you.